# cs0029 cannot implicitly convert type 'ApplicationUser' to 'User'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an app with register and authentication.
I was using this article exactly as in there. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/

I get errors after creating controllers as in the article, before enabling migrations. Of course I can't enable migrations cause lots of errors. **What could I do?**

I searched for answers but mostly it is 'string' to 'int' or something similar.

Full Error: **CS0029 C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'PingGod.Models.ApplicationUser' to 'PingGod.Models.User'**

Also I get some other error but probably the same meaning just other way around: **CS1503 C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'PingGod.Models.User' to 'PingGod.Models.ApplicationUser'**

*Thanks for your help in advance!*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using PingGod.Models;

namespace PingGod.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Users
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Users/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Users users = db.Users.Find(id);  //Here I get error (CS0029)
            if (users == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(users);
        }

        // GET: Users/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Users/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "UserId,Name,Address,City,State,Zip,Email,url")] Users users)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(users);    //Here an error also (CS1503)
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(users);
        }

        // GET: Users/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Users users = db.Users.Find(id);   //Here error (CS0029)
            if (users == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(users);
        }

        // POST: Users/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "UserId,Name,Address,City,State,Zip,Email,url")] Users users)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(users).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(users);
        }

        // GET: Users/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Users users = db.Users.Find(id); //Here eror (CS0029)
            if (users == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(users);
        }

        // POST: Users/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Users users = db.Users.Find(id);  // Here also an error (CS0029)
            db.Users.Remove(users);  //Here other error (CS1503)
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: In the code at the exact line I wrote (//Here error). @Kamo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Users Class are different, that's why you got this error

Use

```
PingGod.Models.Users users = db.Users.Find(id)
```

Maybe this helps u

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Still an error, but Thanks for fast reply! @KanisXXX

Comment: just check Fully qualified class name of both Classes... are both same..?

Comment: Oooh, thanks for getting me on the right road. I solved it!

Comment: What did you change to make it work? Cause I am sitting with the same problem.